# What location does Nominatim return if queried with a larger area e.g "Berlin"?

Tags: geocoding, nominatim

What is the algorithm that determines the returned latitude and longitude when geocoding libraries like Nominatim are queried with a larger area e.g. "Berlin"?

In the example of Berlin, I got "52.51270365 13.3888599", which approximately is the city center. Will the point always be approximately center?

Comment: I think it is the average of the boundingbox of the area.